# Generics Inference when overriding a prop in higher order component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, higher-order-components

I have the following code:

```js
type XType<T> = {
  x: T;
};
function extractTypes<Props, T>(Component: React.FC<Props & XType<T>>) {
  return (props: Props, value: T) => {
    Component({ ...props, x: value });
  };
}


const CompA: React.FC<{ a: string } & XType<string>> = () => <div>HELLO</div>;
const CompB: React.FC<{ b: string } & XType<number>> = () => <div>WORLD</div>;


extractTypes<{ a: string }, string>(CompA)({ a: 'A' }, 'X'); // OK
extractTypes<{ b: string }, number>(CompB)({ b: 'B' }, 1);   // OK

extractTypes(CompA)({ a: 'A' }, 'X');                        // Compile error
extractTypes(CompB)({ b: 'B' }, 1);                          // Compile error
```

`CompA` and `CompB` expect `a` and `b` properties along with all properties in `XType`.

The 3rd-last and 4th-last compile correctly, however the Typescript compiler complains on the last two lines as follows:

```
Argument of type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PropsA & XType<string>'.
  Property 'x' is missing in type '{ a: string; }' but required in type 'XType<string>'.ts(2345)

Argument of type '{ b: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ b: string; } & XType<number>'.
  Property 'x' is missing in type '{ b: string; }' but required in type 'XType<number>'.ts(2345)
```

I've tried many approaches to ensure that I can call `extractTypes` without specifying the types explicitly and still ensure that the method returned by this function accepts only `{ a: string }` or `{ b: string }` instead of `{ a: string; x: string }` or `{ b: string; x: number }`, but to no avail.

Is there any way I can accomplish this without requiring explicit specifying generic types for `extractTypes`?

I think I need to find a way to create a type by subtracting one type (`XType`) from another (`Props`). I've tried using `Omit<Props, keyof XType<T>>` but it doesn't work well here.

Thanks!

Asim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply extend `XType`. This will force you to assert a type internally though.

```js
// adding a default for convenience
type XType<T = unknown> = {
  x: T;
};

function extractTypes<Props extends XType>(Component: React.FC<Props>) {
  // simply index and omit keys in `Props`
  return (props: Omit<Props, keyof XType>, value: Props['x']) => {
    Component({ ...(props as Props), x: value });
    //    assertion --------------
  };
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-LS6UkQWVlPg6fg+dN8HR8OisXAhgBpKOmcwYOOWuA27J25OpuAut2XPmZoLGnPW-PGovXOAARgrckyVdrdZjjeY1gCQWzufZBELxYIZenuIPh8rNYXDcsy9X4EHudb+FHO6nqiPz4Ps5Pp9jF6zQ7zW-wndLMcSz3J8X0xWdlSgHAoFIfVDQGCZJATP9OwnPkPyXGxL3pHMEKcYDy1AsDiJnLJIOgoA)

If you want excess property checking to also work when you pass a reference as props, you can use `Omit<Props, keyof XType> & {[k in keyof XType]?: never}` but this may be overkill given the way people use React.

---

As a side-note, merging the 2 generics was not strictly necessary and your original design is safer, because removing `x: value` will yield an error

```js
 function extractTypes<Props, T>(Component: React.FC<Props & XType<T>>) {
   return (props: Omit<Props, keyof XType>, value: T) => {
     Component({ ...(props as Props), x: value });
    //    assertion ---------------
   };
 }
```

I don't know why though because `Props` is inferred as `{a: string} & XType<string`

Comment: I can use the necessary assertion as suggested, but it also works for `{ ...props } as Props` and even `{ } as Props`. This is fine since I have control of this piece of code. But I want to know how can I properly use typescript such that I don't need to use such potentially code-breaking assertions. =/

Comment: Also, this is an over-simplified example. The requirement is to be able to infer the type of `T` used with `XType`. In my actual code, it has a function which accepts a parameter of type `T`. The second requirement is to be able to infer the actual type of props that were extended with `XType` and used in `React.FC<>`. I have a feeling that we should be able to infer these types within the function somehow.

Comment: I was a bit pessimistic with my assertion. It's possible to only assert `Props` on `props`. When doing so, your original design with 2 generics works better. Try and experiment with your real use case. I don't like having multiple generics when I can avoid it but it does seem to help here.